# Samsung S2 kernel change

Tags: kernel

On my Samsung Galaxy S2, I have Android 4.0.4 running with Kernel 3.0.15-1114882.
I need to change to kernel 3.015-1157945 or 3.015-1056084 .

Is this possible? If yes How?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two means, from a custom recovery or directly from Odin. You will need to find the kernel file apropriate for your phone and then either:

1. Reboot the phone in download mode, connect the USB and use Odin to flash the kernel.
2. Reboot the phone in recovery and flash the kernel.

Just remember that Odin and recovery kernel files are different, so you can't download the Odin file and then flash it from recovery.